# Using SQL to query databases with different RDBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, plsql

I worked through the Mode SQL tutorial ([link](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/introduction-to-sql/)). The tutorial states that it teaches a student how to query a MySQL database. How much do the SQL statements change with different RDBMS's? More specifically, I am mostly concerned with how MS SQL Server's T-SQL and Oracle's PL/SQL differ from the MySQL syntax that I learned? Furthermore, which RDBMS's would allow me to use mostly or entirely the syntax discussed in Mode's tutorial?

Comment: The SQL dialects differ. In some aspects more, in others less. But they differ. Full stop. There's no absolute answer to this. You need to be more precise here. And it the tutorial states, it teaches MySQL my guess would be MySQL is a good choice to go along with it -- who would have thought...

Answer (score 1):

SQL does have a standard - called [ANSI-SQL](https://www.ansi.org/search_results?menuid=search_results&cx=016411134356970301196:ufdyk3moz48&cof=FORID:11&q=SQL&sa=Search). However, I don't know of any RDMBS that fully complies to that standard - every product have it's own dialect. For instance, in MySql you can use `Where (a, b) IN (c,d)` - which is, in fact, a part of the standard - but SQL Server does not allow this. On the other hand, you can use check constraints on both MySql and SQL Server, and they are a part of the standard, but MySql will not enforce them (which is one of the reasons I don't like it - I find it deceiving - if the constraints are not going to be enforced, why would they let you specify them in the first place? just raise an error saying MySql does not support check constraints)

Personally, In the past decade I've worked almost exclusively with SQL server, 
but I can tell you that if you can read the documentation, for most purposes, it's quite easy to switch from one SQL dialect to another.

Also, every RDBMS have it's advantages and disadvantages - some things are better handled by one product and some by another one. The choice of database to work with is usually a matter of licence prices, available hardware, the person's knowledge of the rdmbs system and so on. There is no single *best rdbms* - so there is no single *best sql dialect*.